# How to manage Identity Server 4 Auth Server with Database Configure ability ?

Tags: identityserver4

My Requirements :
 1) identity server clients and api-resource   load from my database not from my static config file.
2) I need to add clients from my API and refresh clients automatically in my AUTH server.

What i did is ,

```
 IEnumerable<Customers> clients = _accountservice.GetAllClients();
            clients.ToList().ForEach((client) =>
            {

                authclients.Add(new Client
                {
                    ClientId = client.ClientId,
                    ClientSecrets =
                    {
                        new Secret(client.ClientSecret.Sha256())
                    },

                    AllowedGrantTypes = GrantTypes.ResourceOwnerPassword,
                    AllowedScopes = {client.AllowScopes },
                    AccessTokenType = AccessTokenType.Jwt,
                    AlwaysSendClientClaims = true,
                    Claims = new List<Claim>() {
                      new Claim("Client Id",client.ClientId , ClaimValueTypes.String)
                    }
                });
            });
```

In my startup.cs

```
services.AddIdentityServer().AddDeveloperSigningCredential()
                .AddInMemoryApiResources(AuthConfiguration.GetApiResources())
                .AddInMemoryClients(AuthConfiguration.GetClients()).AddProfileService<ProfileService>().AddResourceOwnerValidator<ResourceOwnerPasswordValidator>();
```

Every clients loading from database .  First time i was add clients and host in IIS server. 
After i am adding client means i need to restart the server.
But i don't want like that auto refresh option i need in my identity server.

I am using identity server 4.

Answer (score 2):

> 1) identity server clients and api-resource load from my database not
>   from my static config file.

Luckily for you, Identity Server 4 comes with full support for Entity Framework with a lot of configurability options out of the box. You can refer to the documentation page for [Entity Framework support](http://docs.identityserver.io/en/dev/reference/ef.html) where there are quickstarts and guides showcasing how to set everything up to get going.

> 2) I need to add clients from my API and refresh clients automatically
>   in my AUTH server.

There is no out of the box API that would allow you to `POST` new clients. Your option could be to use the aforementioned `IdentityServer.EntityFramework` package and build an API service layer on top of it to add that capability. Having said that, I have implemented OAuth in a few projects and never encountered a justification to build such API. Instead we would create a UI layer to manage (add & edit) OAuth clients. If you think it's something you might be interested in - take a look at the [Identity Server Admin UI](https://www.identityserver.com/documentation/admin-ui/) by the creators of the Identity Server. It is an excellent UI, however, it is a commercial product so you would need to pay.